# mod_proxy overwriting Content-type header

Tags: content-type, apache, mod-proxy

I'm trying to use mod_proxy (apache 2.2) in front of a tomcat (6.0.35) instance. I have this in my apache config:

ProxyPass /Touchpad/ ajp://10.10.6.1:8010/Touchpad/

The client is trying to post a multipart form, and I see the proper header come in on the apache side, but it gets rewritten to text/plain.

I do have a DefaultType set to text/plain globally, but don't understand why that might override the real content type from the client.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem with Apache/2.4.33.  Did you ever find an answer?